# Read data from csv file with foreach function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been reading data from csv, if there is a large csv file, for avoid this time-out(rack 12 sec timeout) i have read only 25 rows from csv after 25 rows it return and again make a request so this will continue until read all the rows.

```
def read_csv(offset)
  r_count = 1
  CSV.foreach(file.tempfile, options) do |row|
  if r_count > offset.to_i
    #process
  end
  r_count += 1
end
```

But here it is creating a new issue, let say first read 25 rows then when the next request comes offset is 25 that time it will read upto first 25 rows then it will start read from 26 and do process, so how can i skip this rows which already read?, i tried this **if next** to skip iteration but that fails, or is there any other efficient way to do this?

Comment: As i have this upload feature for my application

Comment: Did you consider processing the CVS in a background job?

Comment: No because i have to show the final count of how many items are uploaded  to user, also if there any issue with that csv that one also i have to tell to user

Comment: @django were you able to find a solution for this? Could you share for those searching for an answer in the future or mark this complete based on one of the answers provided?

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def read_csv(fileName)
  lines = (`wc -l #{fileName}`).to_i + 1
  lines_processed = 0
  open(fileName) do |csv|
    csv.each_line do |line|
      #process
      lines_processed += 1
    end
  end
end
```

**Pure Ruby - SLOWER**

```
def read_csv(fileName)
  lines = open("sample.csv").count
  lines_processed = 0
  open(fileName) do |csv|
    csv.each_line do |line|
      #process
      lines_processed += 1
    end
  end
end
```

**Benchmarks**

I ran a new benchmark comparing your original method provided and my own. I also included the test file information.

```
"File Information"
Lines: 1172319
Size: 126M

"django's original method"
Time: 18.58 secs
Memory: 0.45 MB

"OneNeptune's method"
Time: 0.58 secs
Memory: 2.18 MB

"Pure Ruby method"
Time: 0.96
Memory: 2.06 MB
```

**Explanation**

*NOTE: I added a pure ruby method, since using `wc` is sort of cheating, and not portable. In most cases it's important to use pure language solutions.*

You can use this method to process a very large CSV file.

~2MB memory I feel is pretty optimal considering the file size, it's a bit of an increase of memory usage, but the time savings seems to be a fair trade, and this will prevent timeouts.

I did modify the method to take a fileName, but this was just because I was testing many different CSV files to make sure they all worked correctly. You can remove this if you'd like, but it'll likely be helpful.

I also removed the concept of an offset, since you stated you originally included it to try to optimize the parsing yourself, but this is no longer necessary.

Also, I keep track of how many lines are in the file, and how many were processed since you needed to use that information. Note, that lines only works on unix based systems, and it's a trick to avoid loading the entire file into memory, it counts the new lines, and I add 1 to account for the last line. If you're not going to count headers as line though, you could remove the +1 and change lines to "rows" to be more accurate.

Another logistical problem you may run into is the need to figure how to handle if the CSV file has headers.

Answer (score -2):

You could use lazy reading to speed this up, the whole of the file wouldn't be read, just from the beginning of the file until the chunk you use.
See http://engineering.continuity.net/csv-tricks/ and https://reinteractive.com/posts/154-improving-csv-processing-code-with-laziness for examples.

You could also use [SmarterCSV](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) to work in chunks like this.

```
SmarterCSV.process(file_path, {:chunk_size => 1000}) do |chunk|
  chunk.each do |row|
    # Do your processing
  end
  do_something_else
end
enter code here
```

The way I did this was by streaming the result to the user, if you see what is happening it doesn't bother that much you have to wait. The timeout you mention won't happen here.
I'm not a Rails user so I give an example from Sinatra, this can be done with Rails also. See eg http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  line = 0
  stream :keep_open do |out|
    1.upto(100) do |line| # this would be your CSV file opened
      out << "processing line #{line}<br>"
      # process line
      sleep 1 # for simulating the delay
    end
  end
end
```

A still better but somewhat complicated solution would be to use websockets, the browser would receive the results from the server once the processing is finished. You will need some javascript in the client also to handle this. See https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails